# while only loop

Tags: java, sql, loops, while-loop

Previously I had a "do while" loop that works really well now. 
This time I can't get my "while" only loop to work.

```
|-----|-------|------|------|
|._id.|..INFO.|.DONE.|.LAST.|
|..1..|...A...|...N..|......|
|..2..|...B...|...Y..|..L...|<--- cursor.moveToFirst();
|..3..|...C...|...Y..|......|
|..4..|...D...|...Y..|......|
|..5..|...E...|...N..|......|
|..6..|...F...|...N..|......|
|-----|-------|------|------|
```

My Code is:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+LAST+" LIKE '%L%'", null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
if (!cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_id)).equals(Long.toString(rowcount)))
{
  while(!cursor.isLast())
  {
    cursor.moveToNext();
    Toast.makeText(context, "your message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

The loop is never entered into, I know this because my toast doesn't pop up. I am just wondering why. I can do this another way, by using a "for" loop, but I am just wondering what I've done wrong with this while loop.

Comment: Also where is etc instantiated?

Comment: Would you add an appropriate language lag like *java* or *sql* to your question?

Comment: The if is entered. And the toast code is: Toast.makeText(context, "before L", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Did the do...while loop execute just once until the isLast() is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will only fetch the row which has the LAST value as 'L'.
The remaining rows will not be fetched. Hence the condition is not reached.